# Why journalctl don't save my logs of the boot before forced shutdown?

Tags: arch-linux, configuration, freeze, journalctl, acpid

My PC freezes a third time and I have to shut it down forcibly. Why doesn't `journalctl` save the boot logs before forced shutdown? When I do `journalctl --list-boots` I only get the boot after crash.

I'm not sorting well or misconfiguration?

System: ArchLinux (5.4.8-arch1-1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the freeze, and it's not clear to me what do you mean by "shut it down forcibly". If this means a power off, definitely, there is no way for your PC to sync data in a proper way. The recommended way to force reboot, is by using the `magic SysRq key` and the `REISUB`sequence. More details are at

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Sysctl

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key

Also, check that `/var/log/journal` exists, writable, persistent and you have enough free space

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And what should I do to keep past boot logs? Because now I only have the log for the current boot session.

Comment: @dlag: Actually, you don't need to do any thing. By default Arch Linux would save the logs if your using a persistent file system. You can tweak the log size by creating `/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/custom.conf` and add SystemMaxUse=1G e.g. For more information https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Journal